# How to express the idea of "I continue to study"

Tags: word-choice, words

I am writing a short text in Japanese and I would like to say that now I am continuing with my study of the Japanese language. Is it better to use the verb 勉強する or 学ぶ?

日本語を勉強し続けている。

日本語を学び続けている。

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what they teach in Japanese-as-a-second-language, but the native speakers' choice would be 「勉強{べんきょう}する」 over 「学{まな}ぶ」 most of the time.

To express different tenses, it would sound more natural to add external words than to just rely on the verb forms and conjugations.  In this case, I would suggest using 「今{いま}でも」 and/or 「まだ」 and say:

> 「（今でも and/or まだ）日本語{にほんご}を勉強しています。」

Using 「勉強し続{つづ}けています」 instead of 「勉強しています」 here is grammatical, but the sentence would sound a little wordy if you used it because 「今でも and/or まだ」 already expresses the continuity of the activity.

If you must use 「続ける」 for some reason, however, you could simply go with your first sentence.

Comment: まだ日本語を勉強しています is certainly the phrase I use.